# The usage of "Not all of them" as Subject

Tags: phrase-usage

The members of a family want to go on a picnic, But not all of them.
Is it correct to say:
"Not all of them want to go on a picnic" ?

Comment: If not all the members want to go, then your first sentence should not start with *the members,* but *some members.* In addition, either put a period (.) after *picnic* or uncapitalize *but.* And remove the space before the question mark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is correct to say "Not all of them want to go on a picnic" so long as the antecedent of *them* is clear.